# Laravel 4 - extending blade, problems with command without brackets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to extend blade in laravel 4 to have some custom commands and I want to call them without brackets. For example I want to call:

```
@test
```

So I've created Blade::extend function like so:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('test');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo "test"; ?>', $view);
});
```

It works fine when I call it with:

```
@test()
```

But fails when I call it with just:

```
@test
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing was with preg_replace pattern. Diving into `BladeCompiler` I found out that it has more that one `createMatcher` method.

To call

```
@test
```

without brackets, just change

```
$pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('test');
```

to:

```
$pattern = $compiler->createPlainMatcher('test');
```

which creates proper pattern in that case.